# Issues with manually linking GLFW using g++/gcc compiler

Tags: c++, compilation, g++, glfw

I'm trying to compile a basic glfw application. My project structure looks like this:

```
project/
  main.cpp
  glfw/
    glfw3.h
    glfw3.lib
```

main.cpp code (directly from glfw docs)

```cpp
#include <glfw3.h>

int main(void)
{
    GLFWwindow *window;

    /* Initialize the library */
    if (!glfwInit())
        return -1;

    /* Create a windowed mode window and its OpenGL context */
    window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Hello World", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window)
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    /* Make the window's context current */
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    /* Loop until the user closes the window */
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        /* Render here */
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        /* Swap front and back buffers */
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);

        /* Poll for and process events */
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

I run this command to compile it:

`g++ main.cpp -o main.exe -Lglfw -Iglfw -lopengl32 -lglfw3`

However, I get this error:

```
C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Temp\ccqBTKoM.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x17): undefined reference to `glfwInit'
C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Temp\ccqBTKoM.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x56): undefined reference to `glfwCreateWindow'
C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Temp\ccqBTKoM.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x64): undefined reference to `glfwTerminate'
C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Temp\ccqBTKoM.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x76): undefined reference to `glfwMakeContextCurrent'
C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Temp\ccqBTKoM.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x81): undefined reference to `glfwWindowShouldClose'
C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Temp\ccqBTKoM.o:main.cpp:(.text+0xa6): undefined reference to `glfwSwapBuffers'
C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Temp\ccqBTKoM.o:main.cpp:(.text+0xab): undefined reference to `glfwPollEvents'
C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Temp\ccqBTKoM.o:main.cpp:(.text+0xb2): undefined reference to `glfwTerminate'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I've tried a lot of things from StackOverflow as well as YouTube, however none seemed to help my case.

Comment: Are you sure you have the right library for your compiler? I assume MinGW is what you are using. The normal library for that would be something like `libglfw3.a`.

Comment: You're right, however I get the same result even when using libglfw3.a

Comment: @Deity Another possibility is mixing 32 bit and 64 bit code.

Comment: How would I know which one I'm targetting here?

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work - I uninstalled all my MinGW stuff and re-installed it using the MSYS2 installer.

```
g++ main.cpp -o main.exe -Lglfw -Iglfw -lglfw3 -lopengl32 -lgdi32
```